# How to match action null for a controller in Grails 3.2.x Interceptor

Tags: grails, grails-controller

interceptors typically come with a matchAll/match matchers. Especially for match

e.g.

```
match(controller: 'draws', action: 'index|details|prizeBreakdown')
```

My question is , when I do a GET to DrawsController, like

```
 /draws
```

action name is

```
null
```

and consequently I never arrive in

```
boolean before()
```

How to match against these requests?

Thanks.

P.S.  I am on Grails 3.2.7 with jdk 8u144

Answer (score 1):

I would say this is a bug.  One way to deal with it is something like this:

```
class SampleInterceptor {

    SampleInterceptor() {
        match controller: 'draws', action: 'index|details|prizeBreakdown'
        match uri: '/draws'
    }

    boolean before() {
        log.debug 'The before interceptor is executing'
        true
    }
}
```

If you file an issue at https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues we can look into it.

Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: We opened  a new issue https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/10831

Comment: Thank you for opening the issue.